# elif statements not working

Tags: macos, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to make this code work. If you enter 1, it opens iTunes. If you enter 2, it opens iPhoto, and etc. I used if/elif/else and I've been checking the method over and over again. It seems like it's written properly. Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Please choose one.
echo 1. Open iTunes.app
echo 2. Open iPhoto.app
echo 3. Open iMovie.app
read UserChoice

cd /Users/$USER/Applications
if [ “$UserChoice”=“1” ]; then
 open iTunes.app
elif [ “$UserChoice”=“2” ]; then
 open iPhoto.app
elif [ “$UserChoice”=“3” ]; then
 open iMovie.app
else
 echo “Please choose a number.”
fi
```

Yet every time I run this code, it only listens to the first "if" statement. So if I type 2 or 3, it'll just open iTunes, running the first if statement. Am I not using elif properly or is there another way to make this work?

Comment: This isn't related to the problem, but the code you posted uses "smart quotes", which won't be recognized by the shell. Make sure you use plain ASCII quotes in the script.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying. What are smart quotes and ASCII quotes?

Comment: ASCII quotes are plainer -- they don't curve, and don't have distinguished left and right forms. See the "Background" section of [this](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html). The difference is important: `echo “Please choose a number.”` prints `“Please choose a number.”` *including the quote marks*, because the shell treats them as just part of the string, not delimiters around the string. Compare this with `echo "Please choose a number."` (plain ASCII quotes), which prints `Please choose a number.` (quotes properly recognized and removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put spaces around "="

Like this

`if [ "$UserChoice" = "1" ] ; then`

Also refer [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) for details

Answer (score -2):

use comparator == instead, [ “$UserChoice”=“1” ] assign 1 to UserChoice and return true => the statement is always true.

Comment: I checked the Apple Documentation for Shell Scripting. It seems to only use = not ==

Comment: Nope, it's the spaces that're the problem. `==` is a nonstandard bashism, the standard `[` command (aka `test`) only supports `=`.

Answer (score -2):

Put semicolons after open XX.app statements. And ensure you're using == checks (compare)  rather than = (assign)

Comment: No on both; you're thinking of some other language.